# How do you set the Colorbox to start at slide 1 on autoopen?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

If you use colorbox, how do you ensure slide 1 always shows first?
For some reason, colorbox always shows on the last slide e.g. Image 9 of 9.

**Updated:**
Here is an example of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/mSWPC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), you should be able to use the event `cbox_complete` to call `$.colorbox.next()`. Example code:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    $.colorbox.next();
});
```

UPDATE:

I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/518bddd9aa9edfa/52d7d519e345e149) discussion about your problem, though they did not provide a solution for it. And I think the proposed solution is awful. So [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/mSWPC/2/) my suggestion instead:

```
$('.colorbox').each(function() {
    $(this).colorbox({
        html: $(this).find('div').html(),
        rel: 'group1'
    });
}).first().click();
```

Comment: Is there any reason why the colorbox would default to the last slide anyway?

Comment: @Simeon - I've managed to create a new jsfiddle, see original post which has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are looping through your selectors with 'each' and telling each one to open.  So of course the last one will be the one that ends up being displayed.  If you want the first item to be displayed, only open the first item.